# Reading from webpage source randomly fails - Java

Tags: java, regex, url, bufferedreader

This is the strangest thing I've seen happen to me in Java. Here's the situation. I'm try to read from 80+ URL's without any kind of API (it really sucks). The webpages have a common way of displaying the information I need so I can usually locate items of interest with a few regex statements.

Here's an example webpage of which I am trying to read. [Webpage](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/items/normal/boots.shtml)

I have two really sloppy classes to accomplish this:

Tester.java.
The Main method here just reads the URL's off my computer, and for each of them calls a method from the Tools class, which returns an ArrayList. Then it adds all those items from the ArrayList into a larger ArrayList which is what I want output. My program never makes it to this point.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Tester
{
    public static int d2counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> database = new ArrayList<>(); 
        ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>(); 

        try
        {           
            FileReader writer = new FileReader("res/URLs.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(writer);     

            while (reader.ready())
            {
                urls.add(reader.readLine());
            }

            for (String i : urls)
            {
                System.out.println(++d2counter + " " + i);
                ArrayList<String> temp = Tools.readURL(i);

                for (String h : temp)
                {
                    database.add(h);
                }
            }

            Tools.outputArraysToFile(database, "output.txt");

            reader.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }               
    }
}
```

Tools.java. The is a helper class filled with static methods. The only method of interest here is the readURL() method.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

/**
 * Class which will house useful tools for other classes in this program.
 */
public abstract class Tools
{       
    public static ArrayList<String> readURL(String address)
    {
        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();

        try
        {
            // Create a reader to read the webpage.
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(address).openStream()));

            // Line variable to be used by Reader.
            String line = "";

            // Phase 1: Navigate to the desired section of the webpage.
            int counter2 = 1;
            while (reader.ready())
            {
                line = reader.readLine();
                counter2++;

                if (line.contains("MAIN CONTENT"))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!reader.ready())
            {
                System.err.println("ERROR: Reached bottom of document without finding page title.");
                System.exit(1);
            }

            String name, url, type;
            type = "Default";

            // Find the type.
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                line = reader.readLine();

                if (line.matches(".*<B>[A-Za-z\\s]+</b>.*"))
                {
                    line = line.substring(line.indexOf("<B>") + 3, line.indexOf("</b>"));
                    line = line.replace("Normal", "");
                    line = line.replace("Exquisite", "");
                    line = line.replace("Elite", "");
                    line = line.trim();
                    if (line.endsWith("s"))
                    {
                        line = line.substring(0, line.length() - 1);
                    }

                    type = line;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Phase 2: Add data:
            while (!line.contains("END MAIN CONTENT"))
            {
                line = reader.readLine();

                if (line.contains(".gif"))
                {
                    line = line.replaceFirst(".*src=\"", "");
                    url = "classic.battle.net" + line.substring(0, line.indexOf("\""));

                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    {
                        line = reader.readLine();

                        if (line.matches(".*<b>[-A-Za-z\\s]+</b>.*"))
                        {
                            line = line.replaceFirst(".*<b>", "");
                            line = line.replaceFirst("</b>.*", "");

                            name = line;
                            temp.add(name + "," + type + "," + url);

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            reader.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Unable to read from URL.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return temp;
    }
}
```

Here's the weird part: **the program fails seemingly randomly every time I run it.**

[image: First run]

[image: Second run]

[image: Third run]

**EVEN MORE WEIRD** is that if you visit those webpages, you'll find that they ALL have "MAIN CONTENT" in their code, which my .contains("MAIN CONTENT") line should have detected. I added in helper print statements to display what URL it gets stuck on and that line is present. Everytime I use the Debugger, it works as I follow it. Due to thousands of lines of input though, I can't seem to effectively breakpoint my way through it all. I don't understand -- There must be something I am missing here.

Thank you all!

Comment: Tried it and unfortunately it did not seem to change anything. The program never reaches that line anyhow as it fails within the `for (String i : urls)` loop.

Comment: My quick gut guess is that the webserver is not sending you the document you think you are getting. Maybe you are being denied for hitting the server too often, or maybe you are being served an interstitial ad or something weird.

Store all the lines for the URL into a local buffer, put a breakpoint on your "ERROR: Reached bottom of document without finding page title." line and inspect the contents of the retrieved document and your URL connection state.

Comment: @goldsz Turns out you were right. So what I did was put a Thread.sleep(2000) and sure enough it made it through ~30 webpages without failure. Unfortunately no matter how much I made it sleep, I couldn't get past around that amount. So what I did is just create a for loop and basically write to a file on every single webpage and then when it'd fail on say... webpage #24, I'd just set the for loop to start at URL 24 and then incrementally get all of them. Still really odd. Must be something about this webserver not wanting to send out that many pages to one IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `ready()` method incorrectly--in fact, you shouldn't be using it at all.  It's causing your program to stop reading when there is still data to be read.

The `readLine()` method is all you need.  When you reach the end of the text, it returns `null`, and **that's** what you use to control the loop.  The standard idiom is:

```
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // process the line
}
```

When `ready()` returns `false`, it doesn't mean there's nothing left to read, it means the underlying stream isn't ready to read at the moment, and there are no characters in its buffer.  In other words, the BufferedReader has to wait--probably a few milliseconds--to access more characters.  It's a low-level method that shouldn't even have `public` visibility, in my opinion.  Many have fallen into this trap before you.

Comment: Interesting. For future reference, are there any higher level ways of reading webpages then? It sounds like the way I'm going about it may not be the best. Would you suggest to avoid BufferedReader?

Comment: Generally speaking, it's best to use a dedicated HTML parser.  Short of that, `java.util.Scanner` will handle all the I/O for you, and its `findWithinHorizon()` method lets you do regex searches on the document just like `Matcher.find()` does on a String.